# Sidebar menu hide the elements on safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

When I open the menu in chome and firefox it works normally, but when it opens in Safari the menu opens but the options outside the menu bar does not appear, I have inspected the code for several hours and tested but not gotten a satisfactory result. Could anyone help me with this problem?

[When I open the menu the information are hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pShn.png)

[When I put my mouse on shows me the elements list exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18LNh.png)

You can access my code on codepen: https://codepen.io/Kadijna/full/GRKbWqg

because I'm using sass and can't put in the compiler below:

```js
var isActive = false;

$('.menu-touch').on('click', function () {
  console.log('cliquei');
  if (isActive) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.drop-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.drop-menu').addClass('menu-open');
  }

  isActive = !isActive;
});

$('.drop-menu .menu-content ul li.btn-clique').on('click', function () {
  if (isActive) {
    $('.menu-touch').removeClass('active');
    $('.drop-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
  } else {
    $('.menu-touch').addClass('active');
    $('.drop-menu').addClass('menu-open');
  }

  isActive = !isActive;
});

$('.drop-menu .menu-content ul li .submenu li').on('click', function () {
    $('.menu-touch').removeClass('active');
    $('.drop-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
});
```

```css
$bg-gray: #fcfcfc;
$bg-orange: #FCEED6;
$bg-blue: #FAFCFD;
$gray: #4a4a4a;
$gray-primary: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
$gray-secondary: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
$lightgray: #B0AFB0;
$blue: #3478c7;
$royal: #022757;
$orange: #FCC351;
$blue2: #74AAE9;   

.multi-collapse{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu-collapse{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-flex;
        padding: 15px 0;
        li{
            color: $gray;
            padding-left: 30px;
            font-size: 2.1rem;
            font-family: ApercuMedium;
            a{
                color: $gray-primary;
                display: inline-block;
                &:after{
                    display:block;
                    content: '';
                    border-bottom: solid 3px $blue;  
                    transform: scaleX(0);  
                    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
                  }
                &:hover{
                    color: $blue;
                    text-decoration: none;
                } 
            }
            a:hover:after, a:hover.line-menu {
                transform-origin:  0% 100%;
              }

            a:hover:after, a:hover:before { transform: scaleX(1); }   
        }
    }
    .drop-menu{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    
        .menu-content {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background: #fcf2e0;
            position: fixed;
            transform: translateX(100vw);
            transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(.56,.1,.34,.91);
            padding: 0;
            z-index: 8;
            overflow: auto;
            .container{
                height: -webkit-fill-available;
            }
            .grid-menu{
                height: inherit;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                .img-menu{
                    background-image: url(/images/computer.png);
                    height: 75vh;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                }
                .navbar-side {
                    margin: 0;
                    list-style: none;
                    padding: 0;
                    padding-top: 40px;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                   
                    li {
                        font-size: 3.2rem;
                        font-family: ApercuMedium;
                        color: $gray-primary;
                        position: relative;
                        a{
                            color: $gray-primary;
                            display: inline-block;
                            &:after{
                                display:block;
                                content: '';
                                border-bottom: solid 3px $blue;  
                                transform: scaleX(0);  
                                transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
                              }
                            &:hover{
                                color: $blue;
                                text-decoration: none;
                            } 
                           i{
                                font-size: 25px;
                            }
                        }
                        .item-menu:hover:after, .item-menu:hover.line-menu {
                            transform-origin:  0% 100%;
                          }
    
                        a:hover:after, a:hover:before { transform: scaleX(1); }   
    
                        .line-menu{
                           display: none;
                        }
    
                        .submenu{
                            overflow: hidden;
                            max-height: 0;
                            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
                            list-style: none;
                            padding: 0;
                            margin: 0;
                            li{
                                font-family: ApercuRegular;
                                a{
                                    font-size: 2.8rem;
                                    color: $gray-primary;
                                    &:hover{
                                        color: $blue;
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        &:hover {
                            .submenu{
                                display: block;
                                max-height: 200px;
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }

                .lang{
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                    a{
                        color: $gray-primary; 
                        font-family: RobotoRegular;
                        font-size: 2.2rem; 
                    }
                    a:last-child{
                        color: $blue;  
                    }
                    span{
                        color: $gray-primary;  
                        font-size: 3rem; 
                        font-size: 2.2rem;
                        padding: 0 10px;
                    }
                }

                .info-contact{
                    display: none;
                    div:first-child{
                        a{
                            display: block;
                            color: $blue;
                            font-family: NotoBold;
                            font-size: 2.2rem;
                        }
                    }
                    p{
                        color: $blue;
                        font-family: NotoBold;
                        font-size: 2.2rem; 
                    }
                    .marker{
                        font-family: "NotoRegular";
                        font-size: 1.9rem;
                        color: #236abe;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .social-menu{
                margin: 0;
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                .face, .in{
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 60px;
                    width: 60px; 
                    a{
                        font-size: 2.6rem;
                        color: $blue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .menu-open {
        .menu-content {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }
    header{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 9;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .navbar{
        .menu-touch,
        .menu-touch span {
            display: inline-block;
            transition: all .4s;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .menu-touch {
            position: relative;
            width: 40px;
            height: 24px;
            text-align: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            span {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 4px;
            background-color: $gray-primary;
            border-radius: 4px;
            }
            span:nth-of-type(1) {
            top: 0;
            }
            span:nth-of-type(2) {
            top: 10px;
            }
            span:nth-of-type(3) {
            bottom: 0;
            }
        }
        .menu-touch:not(.active):hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
            width: 70%;
        }
        .menu-touch:not(.active):hover span:nth-of-type(3) {
            width: 35%;
        }
        .menu-touch.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-45deg);
        }
        .menu-touch.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .menu-touch.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(45deg);
            transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(45deg);
        }
        .logo{
            margin: 0;
            z-index: 8;
            a{
                img{
                    height: 35px;
                }
            }
        }
        .bnt-navbar{
            z-index: 10;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .change-lang{
            display: none;
            margin-right: 4rem;
            a:first-child{
                margin-right: 1rem;
            }
            a{
                font-size: 1.8rem;
                color: $lightgray;
                &:hover{
                    color: $gray;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    animation: shake .9s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) infinite;
                    backface-visibility: hidden;
                    transform-origin: top right;
                }
            }
            a.active{
                color: $blue;
            }
        }

    }

    .loader-pag {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background-color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        .blc-loading{
            position: absolute;
            left: calc(50% - 136px);
            top: calc(50% - 72px);
        }
    }
   
    .site-content{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-light justify-content-between">
      <div class="logo navbar-brand d-flex w-50">
        <a href="#home">logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="bnt-navbar d-flex w-50">
        <a class="menu-touch menu" name="button menu" aria-label="button menu" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="drop-menu">
        <nav class="menu-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row grid-menu"> 

              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9">
                <ul class="navbar-side" id="navbarSide">
                  <li class="btn-clique"><a class="item-menu" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-clique"><a class="item-menu" href="#process">Process</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-clique"><a class="item-menu" href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="item-menu" href="#aboutus">Our team <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                      <li><a href="#joinus">Join Us</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#stacks">Stacks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="btn-clique"><a class="item-menu" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                  <li class="bnt-pj btn-clique"><a class="item-menu" href="#startproject">Start a project</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-clique"><a class="item-menu" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>  
                </ul>
                <div class="lang">
                  <a href="/pt/">PT</a>
                  <span> | </span>
                  <a href="/">EN</a>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Removing your `position: absolute;` attribute on you `.drop-menu` selector seems to help, not sure why it's needed so could be worth testing. I think you'd need to also tweak your flex alignments and overflows too though.